# Use Alphabet[] as a variable in a function

Tags: functions, variable

I'm trying to figure out if I can use the letters contained in Alphabet[] as variables for a function. As a simplified example, I'd like to do something like:

```
g[a_] := f[Alphabet[][[1]]]
```

Which however doesn't work since if I call, for example, g[3] it returns again f[a], rather than f[3].

Does anyone know a way out?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

To explain better what I need this for. I have a defined a function which, given a Lagrangian, computes the corresponding Feynman rules. The function is such that when it is called, for example, as:

```
FeynRule[dot[\[DoubledPi]]^3]
```

It returns:

```
6 \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \("a"\)]\) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \("b"\)]\) \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \("c"\)]\)
```

Which is actually correct.

However, I would like user to be able to replace the a,b,c,... labels with whatever they want; including sums of labels.

The solution of using Symbol@Alphbet[][[1]] does work, but as anticipated by Lucas Lang, it does not work with SetDelayed[].

Is there a better way of doing it?

**EDIT 2**

As a practical example, I've simplified my function, which now looks like this:

```
FeynRule[L_] := Do[
  n = Exponent[L, del[x].del[x]];
  y = Product[
    Sprod[Alphabet[][[i]], Alphabet[][[i + 1]]], {i, 1, n}];
  Return[y];
  , 1]
```

where Sprod[,] is a function I have defined somewhere else, whose only properties I'm interested in are that Sprod[x+y,z]=Sprod[x,z]+Sprod[y,z], and that it's symmetric on its two arguments.

Now, if I run a simple example for the FeynRule function:

```
FeynRule[del[x].del[x]]
```

it correctly gives:

```
Sprod[Alphabet[][[1]], Alphabet[][[2]]]
```

Now, I would like to be able to define a function by simply doing

```
f[a_,b_]:=FeynRule[del[x].del[x]]
```

So that, for example, f[a+b,c] returns Sprod[a,c]+Sprod[b,c]. This is the part that does not work. The only work around I've found so far is to do:

```
f[c_, d_] := 
 FeynRule[del[x].del[x]] /. 
  Sprod[Alphabet[][[1]], Alphabet[][[2]]] -> Sprod[c, d]
```

This does work, but it is a bit cumbersome and it would require to explain the user how to do it.

Comment: Do you want `f[3]` or `f["c"]`?

Comment: I'd like to get back f[3], not f["c"]. I'm essentially doing this because I'm writing a code which will have a large number of variables in sequential order, and the alphabet seems to be the best way. Also because the code is supposed to be user friendly, so that different people in my collaboration case use it.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [Symbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html).

Comment: Alphabet returns a string, convert it to a Symbol like C. E. said. I don't really get the intended use, but here's an example: `g[a_] = f[Symbol@Alphabet[][[1]]]`. `g[3]` returns `f[3]`.

Comment: Note that any potential solution will be quite fragile, and none of them will (easily) work with `SetDelayed`, since the substitution of argument values happens too early for you to catch. I would suggest you explain your usecase for this, then we can probably help you to find a cleaner solution for your problem. (Because as it stands, you will for example still have to type out all your variable names on the left side of the function definition)

Comment: Thanks Lukas, you're right. The solution indeed does not work with SetDelayed. I've updated my post with more details. Any idea?

Comment: Could you prepare a small example that shows what you need, does not require external packages and does not use special characters? The easier it is to use the more likely someone will help.

Comment: @Einj Unfortunately, I'm still not sure I understand what you want to do - as Kuba suggested, could you please expand the example to be a bit more self-contained and easier to read? Something like an example input and what you would like to get as result, and how you would like to be able to specify and use the symbols

Comment: Thanks everyone! I've added a practical example with a simplified version of my function. Let me know if this might help!

Comment: If you have lots of variables...why not just pass a `List` as the argument and use regular indexing from that? You might also want to think about passing `Indexed` as an argument so you can do something like `Indexed[var, i]`

Comment: Thanks b3m2a1!! I think to passa List as an argument is the best solution. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative, unless I got your question wrong, but tbh I am not sure I know what you want:

```
rule[n_] := Module[{body},
  body = Product[Sprod[Slot[i], Slot[i + 1]], {i, 1, n}];
  Function @ Evaluate @ body
]

rule[2]
```

> ```
> Sprod[#1, #2] Sprod[#2, #3] &
> ```

```
f = rule[2];

f[a, b, c]
```

> ```
> Sprod[a, b] Sprod[b, c]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need

```
g[a_] = f[ToExpression@Alphabet[][[1]]]
```

worth reminding:
if you use `:=` then it will be like this.

g[3] ->  evaluate f[Alphabet[][[1]]] -> evaluate Alphabet[][[1]] -> get a -> get f[a]

you can run this to see what happens.

```
t = Alphabet[];
g[a_] := f[t[[1]]];
g[3] // Trace
```

I set t because trace the `Alphabet[]` will be a mess.

Comment: Thanks wuyudi! But as it was suggested in the comments, this doesn't really work with SetDelayed, which rathe restrictive for me.